# Python rewrite instead of appending the data in the .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have 50 files that I process, then write output of the each file to the .csv file, but, it gives me only the last file output to the .csv file

```
with open('output.csv','a+') as out:
    out.write(filename)
    out.write('\n')
    out.write('\n') 
    out.write(';''Golden readback from vivado before fault-injection')
    out.write(';''Readback from vivado after the injection')
    out.write(';''Real-Delta')
    out.write('\n')
# original is my data.
    for row in original:
     for col in row:      
      out.write('{0};'.format(col))
     out.write('\n')
    out.write('\n')
out.close()
```

Any idea how can I put all files output to the same .csv file.

Comment: try with only "a" instead a+ and do not out.close()

Comment: Use the `csv` module to create a `csv` file. Also, `out.close()` isn't necessary; the `with` statement will call it implicitly.

Comment: I have already tried with it but no luck.

Comment: What is csv module to create the .csv file, would you please explain @chepner

Comment: It's a [module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are appending your results in your code using 'a+' mode, try 'w+' instead, it should work.

```
with open('output.csv','w+') as out:
    out.write(filename)
    out.write('\n')
    out.write('\n') 
    out.write(';''Golden readback from vivado before fault-injection')
    out.write(';''Readback from vivado after the injection')
    out.write(';''Real-Delta')
    out.write('\n')
# original is my data.
    for row in original:
     for col in row:      
      out.write('{0};'.format(col))
     out.write('\n')
    out.write('\n')
out.close()
```

Comment: @hassan Does original have all the data or is this the code you run for every file after you process it?

Comment: The original has the data that computed for each run. It run for every file @Arnab Sharma

Comment: try using 
     `file = open('output.csv', 'a+')
      for row in original:
         for col in row:
             file.write(str(col))`

Comment: I already tried. No idea what's the problem. May be every time input file changes ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
from itertools import islice
import linecache

path = '*.rbd'
#path='original-adder.rbd'
files=sorted(glob.glob(path))

for filename in files:

 del_lines = 101
 with open(filename,'r') as f:

  i=1
  while i <= del_lines:
   line1 = f.readline()
   i+=1

  i=0    
  count0_bram = 0
  count1_bram = 0
  count0_nonbram = 0
  count1_nonbram = 0
  totalbits = 0
  totalbitsones = 0
  totalbitszeros = 0

  NON_BRAM_bits_zero_original=57411950
  NON_BRAM_bits_ones_original=3110418

  difference_zero_non_BRAM = 0
  difference_ones_non_BRAM = 0


# COUNT NON BRAM

  for i in range(102,1891426):
   line=linecache.getline(filename,i)

   count_zeros=line.count('0')
   count0_nonbram=count0_nonbram+count_zeros

   count_ones=line.count('1')
   count1_nonbram=count1_nonbram+count_ones

  i=0
# to count BRAM

 #lines=islice(fin,1891427,1903714)
  for i in xrange(1891427,2432181):
    line=linecache.getline(filename,i)


   #line=line.strip()
    count_zeros=line.count('0')
    count0_bram=count0_bram+count_zeros

    count_ones=line.count('1')
    count1_bram=count1_bram+count_ones
  i=0

  totalbits=count0_bram+count1_bram+count0_nonbram+count1_nonbram
  totalbitsones=count1_bram+count1_nonbram
  totalbitszeros=count0_bram+count0_nonbram
  difference_zero_non_BRAM = count0_nonbram-   NON_BRAM_bits_zero_original # new -old
  difference_ones_non_BRAM = count1_nonbram-NON_BRAM_bits_ones_original # new - old


  print filename
  print "-------------------------------------------------"
  print "Total Bits:%d"%totalbits
  print "Number of totalbits-zeros: %d." %totalbitszeros
  print "Number of totalbits-ones: %d." %totalbitsones
  print "Number of BRAM-Zeros: %d." %count0_bram
  print "Number of BRAM-ones: %d." %count1_bram
  print "Number of NON_BRAM-Zeros: %d." %count0_nonbram
  print "Number of NON_BRAM-Ones: %d." %count1_nonbram
  print "difference_zero_non_BRAM:%d."%difference_zero_non_BRAM
  print "difference_ones_non_BRAM:%d."%difference_ones_non_BRAM
  print "--------------------------------------------------"



original= [['Total Bits', 77826496,totalbits,totalbits-77826496],['Total number of bits @0',74651972,totalbitszeros,totalbitszeros-74651972],['Total number of bits @1',3174524,totalbitsones,totalbitsones-3174524],['Totalnumber of BRAM bits-zero',17240022,count0_bram,count0_bram-17240022],['Total number of BRAM bits-ones',64106,count1_bram,count1_bram-64106],['Total  number of non-BRAM bits@0',57411950,count0_nonbram,count0_nonbram-57411950],['Total number of non-BRAM bits@1',3110418,count1_nonbram,count1_nonbram-3110418]]
```